# Slideshow not working :/

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
.mySlides {
display:none;
height:200px;
width:800px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
</style>
 <head>
<body>
<script>

var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
    x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
 </script>
  <section id="images">
              <img id="yeah" class="mySlides" src="image1.jpg" />
              <img class="mySlides" src="image2.jpg" />
              <img class="mySlides" src="image3.jpg" />
          </section>
</body>
</html>
```

So i'm not sure why this automatic slideshow isn't working when it was copied almost verbatim from w3schools, the result doesn't display anything. Ive been trying to find out whats wrong with it for about a day and a half now and still no luck, Please Help!

Comment: Please update your answer with what you expect it to do, what it's actually doing and any errors you're getting. This is a QA site, not a code review forum so you have to provide a clear question.

Comment: I edited your question to use snippets (replacing your `image1.jpg`, etc with publicly available images). Not seeing a problem with your code

Comment: It looks good to me as well. The code looked fine and I'm seeing images change in the "Run code snippet" viewer.

Comment: Thank you @Phil, I guess ill just figure out why it decided to work now. since in my actual document it still isnt working

Comment: @Durubie any errors in your console? How about your *Network* console? Do the images load correctly?

Comment: The edit made had taken out the actual script tags since the codes were placed in a snippet....

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this was not working because before the edit, your script tag was before your html tags..hence the script executed the function and raised a couple of errors since your html was not fully loaded...

Place your script tag below your html codes (in this scenario)

**see snippet**

```html
<html>
  <style>
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
      height: 200px;
      width: 800px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>

    <body>
      <section id="images">
        <img id="yeah" class="mySlides" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxjU7k88PhMjr8f7tCmwOhiaik22dtZYY773ZtWG4TSOLgspnOeIhpOHHa" />
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQiUk8V76AvsGFAkDEHVjnZID8iFgB8LF7mQMbVVDB8mLnxb81v1g" />
      </section>
    </body>

</html>
<script>
  var myIndex = 0;
  carousel();

  function carousel() {

    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    console.log(x, myIndex);
    if (myIndex > x.length) {
      myIndex = 1
    }
    x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Good catch. Watch out for that unclosed `<head>` too (there are two opening `<head>` tags)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different implementation of the slideshow that allows auto rotation of the images.

```
var image_number = 0;

function slideshow(num) {
    var images = new Array("image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.png");
    var description = new Array("Title1", "Title2", "Title3");
    var  image_length = images.length - 1;
    image_number = image_number + num;

    if (image_number > image_length) {
        image_number = 0;        
    }
    if (image_number < 0) {
        image_number = image_length;
    }

    // Change <img> src and image description in DOM
    document.getElementById("slideshow").src=images[image_number];
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description[image_number];
    return false;
}

function auto_slideshow() {
    setInterval(function(){
       slideshow(1);

    }, 3000);
}
```